# input aceitar apenas números de entrada

Tags: c#, variáveis, input

```
            Console.Write("X: ");
            int finalX = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Galera, eu gostaria que meu programa não desse erro ou finalizasse se o usuario digitasse como entrada uma letra ou um caractere especial na minha variavel finalX. Há
alguma forma de pedir apenas pra ele digitar novamente? Sem utilizar while ou algo parecido, pois teria que fazer várias comparações.

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode dar uma olhada no [IsNumber](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isnumber?view=net-6.0) e com o retorno gerado pode aplicar as validações necessárias como por exemplo encerrar o sistema ou adicionar um [Loop](https://www.w3schools.in/csharp-tutorial/loops/#:%7E:text=The%20loops%20in%20C%23%20are%20basically%20of%20two,statements%20provided%20by%20C%23%20that%20is%20entry%20controlled.) até que seja informado um número válido.